# Spectrum of coordinate ring

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Is the points of Spec$(\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(f(x,y))$ equal to

the set $\{ (x-a,y-b) \in $ Spec$(\mathbb{C}[x,y]); f(a,b)=0 \}$?

Comment: the points you've written characterize the _maximal_ ideals of this ring. however the prime ideals can be more general; for instance, suppose $f(x,y)$ is the zero polynomial. then the ring is just $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$, and so (eg) $(0)$, $(x)$, and $(y^2+x)$ are all prime ideals not of the form you've described

Comment: if Spec means maximal ideals, then is it true?

Comment: In this case it would be true as $\Bbb C$ is algebraically closed, so by Hilbert every maximal ideal is of the form $(X-a,Y-b)$. Moreover $f\in (X-a,Y-b) \iff f(a,b)=0$